# Civi Campaign in views

Tags: drupal-views, civicampaign

When changing a campaign name it updates in civicrm but not in views anyone have any suggestions how to get it to update in drupal views?

where is civicampaign name stored?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your Campaign name is still in Drupal Views cache. 
Have You try clean Drupal View clear? Button for Clean cache is in: mysite.org/admin/structure/views/settings/advanced.

Which version of CiviCRM and Drupal do You have?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try clearing the cache and it did not help (the change was also made a long time ago) my version of civi is 5.10.3 and Drupal 7.64

Comment: Definitely recommend updating your civicrm and drupal versions as there have been subsequent security releases for both civicrm and drupal since then.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is stored in the database and in order to make the change it needs to be done in the database (like the first name you make for a campaign is what will be shown in drupal views unless you change the name in db) (at least in that version of civi and drupal but i imagine in all versions)